# Can JSP implement CSP nonces?

Tags: jsp, content-security-policy, nonce

CSP nonces have to be generated for every page load.
JSP does not recompile on every page load.

So it looks like JSP cannot be used to implement CSP nonces.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

JSP pages are compiled into servlet Java classes once.
Use JSP custom tag. Each time the compiled servlet runs, it executes the custom tag handler. The handler emits HTML (with  tags referencing nonce), including HTTP header (with CSP policy and nonce value).